# Django get_next_by_FIELD using complex Q lookups

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset, django-q

While creating a front end for a Django module I faced the following problem inside Django core:

In order to display a link to the next/previous object from a model query, we can use the [extra-instance-methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#extra-instance-methods) of a model instance: *get_next_by_FIELD()* or *get_previous_by_FIELD()*. Where FIELD is a model field of type DateField or DateTimeField.

## Lets explain it with an example

```
from django.db import models

class Shoe(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)
    size = models.IntegerField()
```

A view to display a list of shoes, excluding those where size equals 4:

```
def list_shoes(request):
    shoes = Shoe.objects.exclude(size=4)

    return render_to_response(request, {
        'shoes': shoes
    })
```

And let the following be a view to display one shoe and the corresponding
link to the previous and next shoe.

```
def show_shoe(request, shoe_id):
    shoe = Shoe.objects.get(pk=shoe_id)

    prev_shoe = shoe.get_previous_by_created()
    next_shoe = shoe.get_next_by_created()

    return render_to_response('show_shoe.html', {
        'shoe': shoe,
        'prev_shoe': prev_shoe,
        'next_shoe': next_shoe
    })
```

Now I have the situation that the show_shoe view displays the link to the previous/next regardless of the shoes size. But I actually wanted just shoes whose size is not 4.
Therefore I tried to use the **kwargs argument of the *get_(previous|next)_by_created()* methods to filter out the unwanted shoes, as stated by the documentation:

> Both of these methods will perform their queries using the default manager for the model. If you need to emulate filtering used by a custom manager, or want to perform one-off custom filtering, both methods also accept 
>   optional keyword arguments, which should be in the format described in Field lookups.

**Edit:** Keep an eye on the word "should", because then also (size_ne=4) should work, but it doesn't.

## The actual problem

Filtering using the lookup size__ne ...

```
def show_shoe(request, shoe_id):
    ...
    prev_shoe = shoe.get_previous_by_created(size__ne=4)
    next_shoe = shoe.get_next_by_created(size__ne=4)
    ...
```

... didn't work, it throws **FieldError**: *Cannot resolve keyword 'size_ne' into field.*

Then I tried to use a negated [complex lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) using Q objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def show_shoe(request, shoe_id):
    ...
    prev_shoe = shoe.get_previous_by_created(~Q(size=4))
    next_shoe = shoe.get_next_by_created(~Q(size=4))
    ...
```

... didn't work either, throws **TypeError**: *_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD() got multiple values for argument 'field'*

Because the *get_(previous|next)_by_created* methods only accept **kwargs.

## The actual solution

Since these instance methods use the [_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD(self, field, is_next, **kwargs)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L870) I changed it to accept positional arguments using *args and passed them to the filter, like the **kwargs.

```
def my_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD(self, field, is_next, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Workaround to call get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD by using complext lookup queries using
    Djangos Q Class. The only difference between this version and original version is that
    positional arguments are also passed to the filter function.
    """
    if not self.pk:
        raise ValueError("get_next/get_previous cannot be used on unsaved objects.")
    op = 'gt' if is_next else 'lt'
    order = '' if is_next else '-'
    param = force_text(getattr(self, field.attname))
    q = Q(**{'%s__%s' % (field.name, op): param})
    q = q | Q(**{field.name: param, 'pk__%s' % op: self.pk})
    qs = self.__class__._default_manager.using(self._state.db).filter(*args, **kwargs).filter(q).order_by('%s%s' % (order, field.name), '%spk' % order)
    try:
        return qs[0]
    except IndexError:
        raise self.DoesNotExist("%s matching query does not exist." % self.__class__._meta.object_name)
```

And calling it like:

```
...
prev_shoe = shoe.my_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD(Shoe._meta.get_field('created'), False, ~Q(state=4))
next_shoe = shoe.my_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD(Shoe._meta.get_field('created'), True, ~Q(state=4))
...
```

finally did it.

## Now the question to you

Is there an easier way to handle this? Should *shoe.get_previous_by_created(size__ne=4)* work as expected or should I report this issue to the Django guys, in the hope they'll accept my *_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD()* fix?

Environment: Django 1.7, haven't tested it on 1.9 yet, but the code for *_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD()* stayed the same.

**Edit:** It is true that complex lookups using Q object is not part of "field lookups", it's more part of the filter() and exclude() functions instead. And I am probably wrong when I suppose that get_next_by_FIELD should accept Q objects too. But since the changes involved are minimal and the advantage to use Q object is high, I think these changes should get upstream.

tags: django, complex-lookup, query, get_next_by_FIELD, get_previous_by_FIELD

(listing tags here, because I don't have enough reputations.)

Comment: Since this is my first question, any hints to improve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create [custom lookup `ne`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-lookups/#a-simple-lookup-example) and use it:

```
.get_next_by_created(size__ne=4)
```

Comment: Creating an own lookup works! But why isn't it possible to use size__ne out of the box? Since it 'should' behave like other field lookups.

Comment: Because there is no `ne` lookup by default.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the method you've tried first only takes lookup arg for the field you're basing the get_next on. Meaning you won't be able to access the size field from the get_next_by_created() method, for example.

**Edit** : your method is by far more efficient, but to answer your question on the Django issue, I think everything is working the way it is supposed to. You could offer an additional method such as yours but the existing get_next_by_FIELD is working as described in the docs.

You've managed to work around this with a working method, which is OK I guess, but if you wanted to reduce the overhead, you could try a simple loop :

```
def get_next_by_field_filtered(obj, field=None, **kwargs):

    next_obj = getattr(obj, 'get_next_by_{}'.format(field))()

    for key in kwargs:
        if not getattr(next_obj, str(key)) == kwargs[str(key)]:
            return get_next_by_field_filtered(next_obj, field=field, **kwargs)

    return next_obj
```

This isn't very efficient but it's one way to do what you want.

Hope this helps !

Regards,

Comment: Yes, looping over would work too, but yeah I don't really like it, but your solution looks better.

Comment: And I'm not really sure if the computation/db overhead by looping over is lower than using the modified *my_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD*, because every call to get_next_by_FIELD will require an access to the DB. This is why I wanted to solve this using size_ne or Q objects, so that just one DB access delivers the desired result.

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right, your method works really well :)

Comment: Django needs to add an easier way to do this, than using only the datetime field, honestly I can't recall the amount of time I needed to get next and previous objects and finds myself hacking with session (yes I call working with session hacking) I think including `get_next_by_ID or get_previous_by_ID` would have been a better options, unless it's already there and I missed it.